# ECMAScript Modules vs objects-as-namespaces

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, module, namespaces

I've been using Modules that are presented with ES6 for a while. While I (instinctively) know that it is better to use them, I struggle to explain why.

With modules;

- I can do dependency declaration (not injection). I do not have to use a script tag for each javascript file I load.
- Before modules, objects served as namespaces. Now that we have modules, we have namespaces which is a better paradigm for code organization.

Else than this, why should I use modules ?

What advantage they provide over just using objects as namespaces ?

EDIT:

Thanks to the comments of Bergi and Randy Casburn, I am now able to point out two more things.

- With Module Pattern(which i been calling object-as-namespaces) we have same functionality. But we get it through closures. In Modules, we have separate files. Features of a separate file is harder to be violated.
- Modules hide their internal features. It drives us towards thinking about better software design.

Comment: This: [SOLID Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID) through [Modular Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_programming)

Comment: @Randy Casburn sorry for not stating my question clearly. Please see the last line.

Comment: I think you mean "dependency declaration", not "dependency injection".

Comment: Are the reasons you already listed not enough?

Comment: @Bergi yes they are as i am already using modules. I wonder how they differ from the traditional objest as namspace method in practice.

Comment: I understand your question clearly. The answer to your question is "this is software, do it anyway you want", or "its a choice". But software _design_ is not software coding. There are good designs and other designs. Using modules facilitates good design. Good design can be achieved without modules, but the design is more prone to devolution over time where modules are not.

Comment: @RandyCasburn Modules can be achieved with IIFEs and object namespacing, or with ES6 module syntax - it doesn't really matter for the design.

Comment: @Bergi - Sure "do it any way you want" is valid. I believe ES6 modules (I should have been clear above) provide us with better tooling to achieve the same goal for the reasons I stated.

Comment: @RandyCasburn Better tooling, yes. But they don't facilitate good design more than old-style modules.

Comment: @Bergi exactly. Except the fact that modules are the better paradigm, what do I get if I use modules - if there are anything else than the ones I stated ?

Comment: @Randy Casburn I think we are near the answer. Can you explain the better tooling ?

Comment: @Bergi - we can agree to disagree. How many questions are asked daily about the how and why of import/export and not exposing state or internal features? The "tooling" drives us toward thinking about the hows and whys of SOLID without even knowing the principles - that is the benefit - IMO.

Comment: @RandyCasburn I think the only thing that immutability and scope encapsulation drive us toward is Separation of concerns - but not OLID. (And notice that the old-style module pattern did provide a private scope as well).

Comment: @Doruk - Tooling: 1) segregation on a file basis rather than closure basis (closures are frequently misunderstood (violated) - a separate file is not; 2) Standardized mechanism for what is exposed/not exposed from the module: as Bergi points out, we've done this for a long long time in "various, non-standard ways" (module pattern): but with ES6 modules we import what is exported - simple & direct; etc.

Comment: @Bergi - open-close (O)? absolutely facilitated; substitutability (L) is easily accomplished because of export/import requirement (almost interface like); - And yes absolutely agree that the module pattern (I've relied upon for years) provided much of this - but, I'll reiterate, in a way that makes it too easy to mangle a good design. Just hack more code into that IIFE or object literal. With a file named `doX.js` it is _less_ likely a frail human would put code in there to `doY` stuff.

Comment: I almost marked for close due to "primarily-opinion-based". Perhaps that was the right COA.

Comment: thanks for great comments. i'll upvote if you made them an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question. Thanks for the comments.

- Modularity is a must for software. Before ES Modules, we achieved modules through **Module Pattern**(which is simply putting related things in an object). By ES6, Modules are native. And **native is always the better option**.
- In Module Pattern, we made modules with closures. In ES Modules we code them in seperate files.

  - Seperate files adds another layer of protection against code violation.
- Modules drive us to design better software.

  - With ES Modules we have export keyword which gives us freedom to choose what to expose.
  - We also have import keyword to pick whatever we want from a module.
- With ES6 Modules we can now include Javascript modules which are in seperate files into our web app without the need to include them in script tags.